# Tight Vnc shows multiple monitors blank

Tags: vpn, vnc

One of my users uses VPN from his house to the workplace network and then with tightVNC connects to workstations.

Most of the workstations he can view all 4 monitors from his pc while rolling the screen from one to another.

One workstation shows him one monitor, and when he rolls all other monitors shows black blank results.

Anyone got simillar problem before?? any idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall => Install => Works.